# How to decide whether to put logic in API Route or Server Component in Next.js 13+?

Tags: api, architecture, next.js13

I'm new to Next.js and I wonder about route handler use cases... Should I consider these API routes like a backend as it own for my application and do some logic here?

Or should/can I put the logic directly inside the server component? In this case what if this component needs to be "client" one (e.g. forms interactions) AND "server” (e.g. database interactions)?